# java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, android-activity

In my app, i have a SplashScreen activity. I have setStateLocked error when i clicked on the app. I'm using Fortune Ship MTN-S730 running android 5.1.

Here is the onCreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen); /* logcat says error on this line */
}
```

The says the says that error is on the line with

> setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

here is the output from the logcat

```
setStateLocked: wasEnabled = false, mIsEnabled = false, wasTouchExplorationEnabled = false,
    mIsTouchExplorationEnabled = false, wasHighTextContrastEnabled = false, mIsHighTextContrastEnabled = false
java.lang.Throwable: setStateLocked
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.setStateLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:553)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.tryConnectToServiceLocked(AccessibilityManager.java:636)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.<init>(AccessibilityManager.java:226)
  at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.getInstance(AccessibilityManager.java:206)
  at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:9843)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.initViewGroup(ViewGroup.java:536)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:525)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:520)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:516)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:512)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:119)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.<init>(PhoneWindow.java:2326)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3460)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3846)
  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2042)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:371)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:320)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
  at com.cm_floraison.brandbook.gesu.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:101)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

Here is the manifest declaration of the activity

```
<activity
        android:name=".gesu.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also the content of activity_splash_screen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.cm_toure.myapp.gesu.SplashScreenActivity">

<!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
     is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
     TextureView, etc. -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_brandbook_paysage_sur_fond_blanc"
        />

</LinearLayout>



<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/splash_spinner_style"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="@string/powered_by"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Show `activity_splash_screen.xml` content

Comment: show the manifest declaration of your splashscreen activity and tell which API levels you are building with and your targets.

Comment: @larrytech  I have added the information you required

Comment: @weston  I have added the information you required

Comment: @weston i corrected the error in the layout. It occurred when i was copying the code from my editor to stackoverflow

Comment: @senator First of all using a Framelayout in a framelayout is not cool/appropriate as you nest more unecessary views and that's a cost during view inflation. Now let me see your fullScreen theme style